# extracting pairs from a hand of 7 cards

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I am coding in Python to create a game of GoFish where instead of four of a kind, you are looking for pairs. I wrote a code in python to find pairs in a hand of 7 cards. The code gives a list of all pairs (so it is a list of list). Since I am new to Python, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to achieve what my code does.

Here is the code I wrote. Eventually, it will become a function inside a class.

```
#hand = ['D2', 'S1', 'D3', 'H1', 'C1', 'H5', 'D5']
#hand = ['D1', 'S1', 'S2', 'H2', 'C1', 'H5', 'D5']
#hand = ['D1', 'S1', 'S2', 'H1', 'C1', 'H5', 'D5']
hand = ['D1', 'S1', 'C1', 'H1', 'C2', 'H2', 'D5']
#hand = ['D2', 'S1', 'C3', 'H4', 'C5', 'H6', 'D7']

list_of_pairs = []
i=0
while i < len(hand):
    current_pos = i
    for k in range(i+1, len(hand)):
        card_1 = hand[i]
        card_2 = hand[k]
        if card_1[-1:] == card_2[-1:]:
            pair_2 = hand.pop(k)
            pair_1 = hand.pop(i)
            pair = [pair_1, pair_2] 
            list_of_pairs.append(pair)
            i = current_pos - 1
            break
    i +=1 

print(f"List of pairs is {list_of_pairs}")
print(f"Left over hand is {hand}")
```

Comment: Perhaps better on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Mateen I don't think OP wants his code reviewed but a more efficient algorithmic approach to his/her brute force attempt. Stackoverflow (algorithm tag) looks pretty suitable for that.

Comment: Concerning the algorithm : for a large number n of cards, you will have a gain by sorting the cards and getting O(nlogn) complexity. Here n=7, you only have 21 pair candidates. So a brute force approach seems quite competitive.

Answer (score 0):

```
hand = [1,1,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,7,8,9,9]
hand_set = set()
pairs = set()
for card in hand:
    if card in hand_set:
        pairs.add(card)
    else:
        hand_set.add(card)
```

if tow pairs of same card is possible

```
from collections import Counter
hand = [1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,7,8,9,9,9,9]
card_counter = Counter()
for card in hand:
    card_counter[card]+=1

pairs = []
for k in card_counter:
    for i in range(int(card_counter[k]/2)):
        pairs.append([k,k])
```

Comment: If you're going to use `Counter`, just write `card_counter = Counter(hand)`, without the loop. Writing a loop to do the counting yourself somewhat defeats the point of using `Counter`.